# DateTime Format like HH:mm 24 Hours without AM/PM

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

I was searching here about converting a string like "16:20" to a DateTime type without losing the format, I said I dont want to add dd/MM/yyy or seconds or AM/PM, because db just accept this format.

I tried with Cultures yet

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All DateTime objects must have a date and a time.

If you want just the time, use TimeSpan:

```
TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.Parse("16:20");
```

If you want a DateTime, add that time to the min value:

```
TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.Parse("16.20");
DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue.Add(span);
// will get you 1/1/1900 4:20 PM which can be formatted with .ToString("HH:mm") for 24 hour formatting
```

Comment: I will try this, cause i see that the other developer who works whit C++ was storing the data like you specify.

Comment: is possible to remove the AM/PM at last format? and makes it 24 hours , thanks in advance

Comment: DateTime objects don't store dates in a specific format. You can display them however you like. dt.ToString("HH:mm") will get you the 24-hour representation

Comment: The second TimeSpan object example is not 100%, should have a ":" instead of a "." -  
TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.Parse("16:20");

Answer (score 26):

Just give a date format to your dateTime.

`string DateFormat = "yyyy MM d "` this willl give you the **year month and day**. after continuing; 
`string DateFormat = "yyyy MM d HH:mm:ss "`  in here the **Capital H** will give you the `24 hours time format` and lowerCase `"h" will give you the 12 hours time` format...

when you give the Dateformat as a string you can do whatever you want with date and time.

```
string DateFormat = "yyyyMMdHHmmss";
string date = DateTime.Now.ToStrign(DateFormat);
```

OR

```
Console.writeline(DateTime.Now.ToStrign(DateFormat));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
20120823132544
```

Comment: +1 for "HH will give you 24 hour format" never knew this, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm") - If it's C#.

Oh. Only read the header.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2008, 12, 11, Convert.ToInt32("16"), Convert.ToInt32("32"), 0);
```

Comment: capital h's for 24 hour time

Comment: but this convert the value to string right? i want to set it datetime type cause i work with a class that contain an attribute for this value

Comment: im getting the value from a gridview In this way:
string hour = ((Label)selectedRow.Cells[0].FindControl("lblHorario")).Text;

Comment: or
DateTime hour = Convert.ToDateTime(((Label)selectedRow.Cells[0].FindControl("lblHorario")).Text);

Answer (score 1):

what do you mean by "losing the format".

if you convert it to a DateTime type, then the DateTime object will have dd/mm/yy and other properties. depending on how you plan to use the object, you can "recover" your original settings, by formatting the string output like this: DT.ToString("HH:mm");

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't stipulate which DBMS you are using, it is hard to know which answer will help you.  If you use IBM Informix Dynamic Server, you would simply use the data type 'DATETIME HOUR TO MINUTE', which will record values in the 24 hour clock.

Comment: but in code side im using linqtosql, so i have to pass all data required as DB types.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime.Parse("16:20")
```

Comment: im getting this with your code snippet:
11/12/2008 04:20:00 p.m.

Comment: Im Still getting FormatException unhandled by user code, by the way now i set DateTime in both sides, server side and client side, so why stills trowing this exception?

Answer (score 0):

I want to address this part of your question:

> without losing the format

A database will generally store all datetime values in a standard common format that's not even human readable.  If you use a datetime column the original format is destroyed.

However, when you retrieve the value you cast it back to any format you want.  If you want `HH:mm` you can get it.

Comment: I fixed the question so the 'with out loose' part of Joel's comment makes less sense now.