# How can i format date time to 24 hour format?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is how i'm formating the date time:

```
for (int i = 0; i < AllNews.Count; i++)
{
    myl.Add(AllNews[i].text);
    IFormatProvider provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    DateTime myTime = DateTime.ParseExact(AllNews[i].original_time, "DyyMMddTHHmm", provider);
    string results = myTime.ToString("hh:mm דווח במקור בתאריך : dd.MM.yy : שעה");
    myl.Add(results);
    myl.Add(AllNews[i].link);
    myl.Add(Environment.NewLine);
    myListWithoutLinks.Add(AllNews[i].text);
    myListWithoutLinks.Add(results);
    myListWithoutLinks.Add(Environment.NewLine);

}
```

But when it's night i see 12:46 and when it's noon 12:46. Same for 07:00 morning or evening.
How can i make that when it's 7PM it will show 19:00 and when it's 7AM it will show 07:00 ?

Without AM/PM near it.

Comment: So you don't want to format it to am/pm (as your title asks), but want to format it to 24-hour time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [DateTime Format like HH:mm 24 Hours without AM/PM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/360982/datetime-format-like-hhmm-24-hours-without-am-pm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use "HH" for 24-hour time.  You have "hh", which is 12-hour time.

Comment: See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the full list of what strings map to what values.