# Jquery expecting The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" after dot net core upgrade to 2.1

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, .net-core, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Before upgrading the project from 1.x to 2.x, the date time worked fine with the format ('mm/dd/yyyy'). After the upgrade `The specified value "30-Tu-yyyy" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS".`

Am using datetimepicker on client side.

Also, tried adding the following annotation to the model property

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{mm/dd/yyyy}")]
```

This din't work as well.
Issues are with the following code

```
$('#RequestDate').datetimepicker({
        showClear: true,
        ignoreReadonly: true,
        format: 'L'
    }).on('dp.change', function (e) {
        var endDateMinDate = e.date.add(14, 'days');
        $('#CompletionDate').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(endDateMinDate);
    });
```

The UI started looking as follows.

[image]

How to solve this issue? Do I have to add anything else?

Comment: I believe you need to change 'mm/dd/yyyy' to 'MM/dd/yyyy'

Comment: @Pintang That just changes my warning from Jquery to "The specified value "September/19/2018" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS"."

Comment: "yyyyMMdHHmmss" - "yearMONTHdayHOURSminutesseconds"

Comment: are you wanting to get and or display `AM/PM` for example..? if so you need to remove the `T` and have `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss:tt` have you tried that ..?

Comment: No, I don't need hh:mm:ss:tt. I only need yyyy-MM-dd. But the default somehow seems to be expecting yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm

Answer (score 1):

```
string DateFormat = "yyyyMMdHHmmss";
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString(DateFormat);
```

yyyy MM dd HH:mm:ss - will be year month and day - the Capital H will give you the 24 hours time format and lowercase "h" will give you the 12 hours time format.

Reference: [DateTime Format like HH:mm 24 Hours without AM/PM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360982/datetime-format-like-hhmm-24-hours-without-am-pm)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my issue is on the UI. Before the on-change is triggered, am getting the error "The specified value "September/19/2018" does not conform to the required format. The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS"." Any ideas regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the party, but for anyone experiencing this problem, the following Razor code produces the error:

`<input asp-for="MyDate" />`

But the following code works as expected:

`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyDate)`

You could also do something like the following, but then the textbox displays the date with that same screwy syntax, so I don't recommend it:

`<input id="MyDate" name="MyDate" value="@Model.MyDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm")" />`